# nginx + node + ssl + websockets, on one server

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I've been able to find guides pertaining to various combinations of nginx, node, ssl, and websockets, but never all together and never on a single server.

Ultimately, this is what I'm after and I'm not sure if it's even possible:

- single server (Ubuntu 14.04)
- forced HTTPS (browsing to http://site forwards to https://)
- node app is hosted on localhost:3000
- node app uses web sockets
- it's a single-page React app with no routing at all, so I don't need routes. I repeat, I'm only hosting one page with no navigation whatsoever.

With the below config, I have everything working except websockets - the client throws an error which doesn't happen if I browse straight to the node server and don't use nginx (browse to http://my.domain:3000):

`bundle.js:26 WebSocket connection to 'wss://<my domain>/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=x1uQtRzF3gYYEvfIAAAi' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://my/domain$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443;

  ssl_certificate     /path/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/key.key;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

  server_name blaze.chat;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3000 https://my.domain;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right, got it working... Found a lot of articles all showing similar things but missing these key lines:

```
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
```

In my case, websockets won't work without those lines, contrary to many other posts where similar questions were asked. Not sure what the difference was. Ironically it is listed as a requirement in the Nginx Websocket Proxying doco... Should have started there, my bad.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Side note, I am just using this on the root path of `/` which works fine.